# Domains pointing on same directory

Tags: linux, nginx, web, server, dns

In fact I have 2 domains `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`

I ask how to do that when I access `domain1.com/secret` it'll show `domain2.com` root directory in `nginx`, `domain1.com` is on another server but show only when secret is accessed other way show local root directory for `domain1.com`

Please don't be rude its my first question, just constructive critique.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, do you need to redirect the user from domain1/secret to domain2 (ie, the URL will change in the browser), or just show the contents of domain2 transparently to the user?

Comment: show the content of domain2, make this /secret to point to the root directory of domain2 on another nginx server

Comment: I think what you need is a reverse proxy: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/